What's the criteria to be able to view the time recipients spent reading an email Outlook on the web?
I've sent an email using Outlook on the web. I read  on Outlook on the web:

"Not enough data to measure time spent reading this mail.


What's the criteria to be able to view the time recipients spent reading an email Outlook on the web?
